Requesting reliable references for the Physical Meaning of Differential Geometry objects in General Relativity
I am seeking to understand the physical significance of certain differential geometry objects commonly used in general relativity, such as:

The Ricci tensor
The Ricci scalar (curvature scalar)
The Kretschmann scalar
The Einstein tensor
Other related geometric objects

While I am familiar with their mathematical definitions, I am particularly interested in how these quantities are interpreted physically, what these quantities describe in terms of spacetime curvature, as well as their roles in specific scenarios like black holes or cosmology.
Could anyone recommend reliable books or articles that discuss these objects from a physical perspective? I am looking for sources that bridge the gap between the mathematical formalism and the physical intuition behind these tensors and scalars.

Physical and Geometric Interpretations of the Riemann Tensor, Ricci Tensor, and Scalar Curvature. Various interpretations of the Riemann Curvature Tensor, Ricci Tensor, and Scalar Curvature are described. Also, the physical meanings of the Einstein Tensor and Einstein's Equations are discussed. Finally a derivation of Newtonian Gravity from Einstein's Equations is given.
